# Read-only file system error while creating a directory?

Tags: 12.04, mount

I have got one of our production ubuntu machine setup by PRODUCTION Unix team here in our company but somehow when I am doing like this -

```
root@machineA:/test01# ls -lt
ls: reading directory .: Input/output error
total 0
```

It is giving me an error and also if I am trying to create any directory in the promary01 directory, it is giving me an error as well -

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `/test01/primary': Read-only file system
```

Any thoughts what is wrong? I am thinking to fix this myself instead of telling UNIX PROD guys as I have the root access with me as well and I will be able to learn something new as well.

May be, it was not mounted properly?

Answer (score 2):

Likely the partition was mounted with the `errors=remount-ro` option, that means, if an error is encountered on the file system it will be remounted read-only. Then you encountered an I/O error (which is usually a hardware error because of a failing disk). Because of that I/O error the partition got remounted read-only.

You can check the current mounts with simply `mount`. You can try remounting the disk read-write, but since it is a production machine, with a likely hardware error, I would just contact the *"guys"*. I won't be happy if I cause a data loss.